# Canvas or what?

Tags: html, canvas, social-networking

I'm making a social networking site, and it will have a 'group map' which shows all the groups with their importance with lines connecting them all.  Here is an [example](http://social.universestick.com/images/Preview.png) of what I am aiming out.  The problem is I don't know whether to use a HTML5 canvas or something else.  The problem with a canvas, though, is the IE compatibility issues.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is anything about this map dynamic beyond just clicking things? If not why not generate the image server side?

Comment: You can click a group, and that's about it.  What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Generate the image on the server using some image creation library, possibly [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), then use the [<map>](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) tag for clickability, its contents likely also generated on the server. A bit convoluted I suppose but no more so than doing it all with `<canvas>`, and of course without the compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

For IE you have at least a few options: ex-canvas, http://www.google.com/chromeframe or just ignoring it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Google Charts API? It can generate all kinds of charts and graphs. It may have a chart that you could use for this: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 0):

You could try SVG with Raphael Javascript library, [http://raphaeljs.com](http://raphaeljs.com/). For IE it uses IE's VML, so usually the difference is imperceptible.